# Reading voltages from ngspice to another program

Tags: simulation, ngspice

I am using ngspice for a project and need to do the following:

Read a node voltage from the simulation into another program, process it and change another node voltage in the circuit.

For example :

```
*netlist

v1 a  0 10V

R1 b  a 10

R2 0  b 10


.control

stop when time = 0.01000ms

stop when time = 0.02000ms

tran 0.001ms 0.1ms



alter @v1 = 0V
resume

alter @v1 = 5V
resume

plot v(a) 


.endc
```

In the above netlist, whenever I stop the simulation, I want to be able to read the voltage at node b into another program, do some processing on it (possibly in another program/SW) and change the voltage of node 'a' (v1) depending on the result (of the other program). Any hints about how this can be achieved?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

print is the command you need (in the control deck)

If you need to do some more complex things consider the tclspice extension, there is an optimization example in the manual similar to what you need

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Lorenzo I looked into tclspice also and It does the job for me. But for now I am directly using ngspice as a shared library and can export vectors to my main program using ngGet_Vec_Info() function. That does the job for me .